# What is a Casino Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Casino Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Casino Words™ | Not Casino Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SUCCESS | FAIL |
| GRACE | FAVOUR |
| SWAY | STAND |
| ARGUE | DISPUTE |
| ZOOM | ADJUST |
| RUSSIAN | AMERICAN |
| OFF | ON |
| PRICELESS | WORTHLESS |
| UGLY | BEAUTIFUL |
| LINEAR | NONLINEAR |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Casino Words™,Not Casino Words™
SUCCESS,FAIL
GRACE,FAVOUR
SWAY,STAND
ARGUE,DISPUTE
ZOOM,ADJUST
RUSSIAN,AMERICAN
OFF,ON
PRICELESS,WORTHLESS
UGLY,BEAUTIFUL
LINEAR,NONLINEAR
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think a Casino Word has the property that

> If we convert each letter to its corresponding position in the alphabet (A=1, B=2,..., Z=26) then a Casino word consists entirely of red [Roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette) numbers **or** entirely of black Roulette numbers.

Examples

> $SUCCESS \rightarrow (19,21,3,3,5,19,19)$.
>  All of the numbers in brackets are **red** Roulette numbers. Hence, this is a Casino Word.
>  $ZOOM \rightarrow (26, 15, 15, 13)$
>  All of the numbers in brackets are **black** Roulette numbers. Hence, this is a Casino Word.
>  $STAND \rightarrow (19,20,1,14,4)$
>  This word contains a mix of red and black numbers, hence is not a Casino Word

Comment: Both sides have an S?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry You've misunderstood me. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @hexomino you've won a lot of chips here :P